# Node.js child process with a very long argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I use the Node.js `child_process` to spawn a `jar` file, like so:

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn('java', ['-Xmx1024m', '-jar', 'myJarFile.jar', argString]);
```

While this works for short `string` values of `argString`, I get the following `error` while using a really long `string` as the argument:

```
Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    ...
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: `a really long string` - so, how long is "really long" - at what point (approximately) does this become a problem? (31k perhaps? that is a long string)

Comment: @JaromandaX The string I'm trying to use is about 30,000 characters long. I have been able to use strings about 5,000 long. Not sure at what point it becomes a problem.

Comment: yeah, it's 31k by the look of it - no workaround, why not save the string into a temp file, then pass the temp file name as an argument to the child process instead - of course, then the child process would have to read the file rather than get its input from the command line ... another option would be to pipe output from your node app to the input of the child process - again, child process needs to be rewritten to read from stdin

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error, but for python, and
managed to solve this problem in this way:

JS:

```js
const runPy = (funcName, imageBase64, jsonDocString) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // two short string in params
    const pyLib = spawn(process.env.PYTHON_PATH, ['./server/bridgeJs2Py.py', funcName, jsonDocString]); 

    pyLib.stdin.write(imageBase64); // <-- very long string
    pyLib.stdin.end();

    pyLib.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        resolve(data);
    });

    pyLib.stderr.on('data', (data) => {

        reject(data);
    });
});
```

PY:

```
import library as library
import sys

funcParam1 = input()
funcName = sys.argv[1]


if funcName == 'lib_register_result':
    funcParam2 = sys.argv[2]
    res = library.lib_register_result(funcParam1, funcParam2)
    print(res)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```